# Customized Table in Latex

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I want to create such a table in Latex as shown below. As I[image] am new to latex, so I am unable to create such a desired table. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{tabularx}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{center}

        \begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{|*{5}{X|}}
          \hline
          \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Data analysis} \\
          \hline
          Sample 1&700&True2 &Sen.&         \\
          \cline{3-3}
                  &   &False3&    & Accuracy\\
          \cline{1-4}
                  &800&True4 &    &         \\
          \cline{3-3}
          Sample2 &   &False5&Spe.&         \\
          \hline
        \end{tabularx}

        \end{center}
```